# How to Add the image and text in datagridview cell

Tags: vb.net, image, datagridview

Actually i want to customised the Datagridview cell according to  my requirement.
I've to add text and image to Datagridview row for specific column.
see the following image

[image]

Can any one help me with some example ?
Thanks.

Comment: if u want to achieve that kind of look, WPF is a better option, but you can cutomize your datagridview in winforms also but this kind of look,as far as i know, is impossible/hard to achieve in winforms

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    DataGridView1.ColumnCount = 3
    DataGridView1.Columns(0).Name = "Product ID"
    DataGridView1.Columns(1).Name = "Product Name"
    DataGridView1.Columns(2).Name = "Product_Price"

    Dim row As String() = New String() {"1", "Product 1", "1000"}
    DataGridView1.Rows.Add(row)
    row = New String() {"2", "Product 2", "2000"}
    DataGridView1.Rows.Add(row)
    row = New String() {"3", "Product 3", "3000"}
    DataGridView1.Rows.Add(row)
    row = New String() {"4", "Product 4", "4000"}
    DataGridView1.Rows.Add(row)

    Dim img As New DataGridViewImageColumn()
    Dim inImg As Image = Image.FromFile("Image Path")
    img.Image = inImg
    DataGridView1.Columns.Add(img)
    img.HeaderText = "Image"
    img.Name = "img"

    End Sub
  End Class
```

Answer (score 0):

You can you convert DataGridView cell dynamically to `DataGridViewTextBoxCell()` and display text value to that column. below is code sample that gives you some basic idea.

```
Private Sub button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    dataGridView1.Rows(3).Cells("ImageCol") = New DataGridViewTextBoxCell()
    dataGridView1.Rows(3).Cells("ImageCol").Value = "Hello.."
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

```
       Dim dt As New DataTable

        Dim imageColumn As New DataColumn
        imageColumn.ColumnName = "ActualImage"
        imageColumn.DataType = GetType(System.Drawing.Image)
        dt.Columns.Add(imageColumn)

        For Each row As DataRow In dt.Rows
            row("ActualImage") = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(row("Image_Path"))
        Next

        dt.AcceptChanges()


        Dim dgvImageColumn As New DataGridViewImageColumn
        dgvImageColumn.DataPropertyName = "ActualImage"
        dgvImageColumn.Name = "ActualImage"
        dgvImageColumn.ImageLayout = DataGridViewImageCellLayout.Zoom
        DataGridView1.Columns.Add(dgvImageColumn)

        DataGridView1.DataSource = dt
```